# Need Help Building SortedDictionary of colors, that the user can choose from to change back color

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Entire Question:

Use a SortedDictionary to create a reusable class for choosing from some of the predefined colors
in class Color (in the System.Drawing namespace). The names of the colors should be used as keys,
and the predefined Color objects should be used as values. Place this class in a class library that can
be referenced from any Visual Basic application. Use your new class in a Windows application that
allows the user to select a color and then changes the background color of the Form.

I am curious on how the project should be started. Am I supposed to make a classlibrary named Color?

Comment: Yes, a class library but I wouldn't call it Color. That would conflict with the .net class. Call it something else.

Comment: Answer to only question in the post _Am I supposed to make a class library named Color?_ - name it as you wish.

Comment: Based on the instructions, I'm not sure that you need a class library.  It might be sufficient just to encapsulate it into a class in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can make a list of colors using:

```
Dim clist As New List(Of Color)
```

and then just add colors like:

```
clist.Add(Color.Black)
clist.Add(Color.Red)
```

then loop thru via e.g.

```
Dim CurrentColor As Color
For each MyColor As Color in clist
   CurrentColor = MyColor
   'do whatever you want with this color
Next
```

There is no reason why you can't use a dictionary with a text string like "reds" for a key and list of colors as a value for each key.  Look up how to loop through `KeyValuePair` of a dictionary, or return a list of colors if the key is "reds" and the color list contains e.g. pink, maroon, magenta, red, orange, etc., and you select that list by

```
clist = dicColors("reds")
```

FYI - i wouldn't use a Color as a key, but you probably could.  I always like to use text strings for keys, and then anything in the values, like ListOf(anything)